# How do I construct a connectstring given all the parameters?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0

In C#, how do I manually build a proper connection string? I have the server name, database name, user name, and password. This is a SQL Server database and .NET 4.0.

I looked at the SQLConnectionStringBuilder and that appears to be what I want but I don't know how to specify the server.

Answer (score 4):

On the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) use the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource.aspx) property for the server host name/ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the examples at MSDN:

[MSDN - SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)

The line of code in question:

```
builder["Server"] = yourServerName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource.aspx) Property

Although you could just set the [ConnectionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring.aspx) to something like

```
Data Source =myServerAddress; Initial Catalog =myDataBase; User Id =myUsername; Password =myPassword;
```

For alternative connection string for SQL Server 2008 see

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p1

Answer (score 1):

You're right : `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is the way to go. The `DataSource` property is the server name. You can find more info about this class on the [msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.datasource.aspx). One easy way to figure out what properties you have to set may be to initialize a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` using an existing connection string and seeing which properties are used.

For instance, it's likely that you'll use `IntialCatalog` (the name of the database you want to connect to).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com).

You can use the [`SQLConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) constructor overload that takes a connectionstring as described in the above site.